# Access the Request object on Loopback

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using Loopback(based on Express) and I need to get the request object on a hook as shown below:

```
Model.observe('access', function(ctx, next) {
    console.log(ctx.Model.app.response);
    if(ctx.query && ctx.query && ctx.query.where && ctx.query.where.id == 1){
      next();
      return;
    }
    next(new Error('Model does not exist'))

  });
```

The only problem is that the response contains the app as:

```
IncomingMessage { app: [Circular] },
```

How can I access the request object such as headers?

Answer (score -1):

Use **context.args.id** to access a HTTP request

Answer (score -1):

This could depend on Loopback version and how you have defined the remote method being used to this models function. Have a look in ctx.req